# How can I fix "failed to compile Node.js app"?

Tags: node.js, github, heroku

I keep getting "failed to compile Node.js app." I have fixed the versions in the package-lock files but it keeps giving me the exact same thing.

`-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs -----> Node.js app detected parse error: Expected separator between values at line 11, column 9 !     Unable to parse package.json -----> Build failed We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/ Love, Heroku !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app. !     Push failed`

Comment: It is hard to give any advice not knowing what you are trying to do or without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should take a look at ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then update your question.

Comment: The error message is clear. You have an error in your package.json and this can't be parsed